# Dependencies installed in the same folder are not being detected?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, praw

I'm trying to create a development package for AWS Lambda. One of the modules I am using is praw which has a lot of dependencies such as urllib3 and requests.
I use the command `pip install praw -t .` in the folder where I need to use praw this installs all the dependencies as well. But whenever I try to import praw i get the error message

> File "c:\Script\Modules\praw\reddit.py", line 23, in 
> from prawcore import ( ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prawcore

This happens despite prawcore being installed. If I go into that reddit.py file and replace that code with `from Modules.prawcore import (` then it works but then another dependencies fails and I have to come in and put the `Modules.` bit in. Is there a way to get around this and make sure the dependencies are detected? Or is it some other problem?

Comment: Did you check my answer? If it solved, please remember to accept it (helps a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Ah I think you need to deploy Lambda and all code packages as zip folder and upload them in AWS. Did you check that when you do `pip install praw -t .`  you will get library folder? So, just zip that with lambda code and upload as a zip folder

[image]